# .net testing app

Tags: .net, unit-testing

i'm using vs2010's standart unit tests, for example, i want to get all information like used variables with their values, called functions, etc. in readable form, xml forexample. how can i do it?

Comment: XML readable?!! What are you smoking?

Comment: lol, i dont care, any readable form, for people

Comment: fwiw the code should be readable, if it isn't there is a problem

Comment: Can I ask why you want this?
You might be interested in http://sequenceviz.codeplex.com/releases/view/18286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on a test -> Create Performance Session.

That way you can profile your test. Using the Instrumentation option, you'll get: function call counts and timing.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for code coverage. Not sure if this built into the VS unit tests. I used to use NCover if I ever needed such a metric.

Comment: How did you get code coverage from that? I'm impressed. VS2010 includes code coverage. 
http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/dave/archive/2009/10/27/code-coverage-in-vs2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Which version of VS 2010 do you have? If you have Premium or Ultimate you can take a look at this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsunittest/thread/eb7f6c78-c4ea-4020-a22e-db0e43d4a167

Answer (score 0):

You can get all functions calls and function parameters using [Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me).